# Textual Convention for Class + Selector names in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to have a basic conversation about some code in Objective-C and I'm curious how people would format the fully qualified name of a selector.

For example in C++, the empty method of the vector class would most likely be written out as `std::vector::empty` when you would want to make sure the person you are communicating with unambiguously knows which method you are speaking about. The equivalent in Java would be `java.util.List#isEmpty` or slightly less than ideal `java.util.List.isEmpty`.

Is there a similar convention in Objective-C?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely :-) It's called a "Selector" and is a first-class thing in the Objective-C runtime.

Check out the [Objective-C Runtime Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

It's usually formatted with the colons in place, but no spaces, like this:

```
setFoo:withBar:
```

But keep in mind that this does not specify a recipient class (e.g. it is very intentionally not associated with a class or instance.

Comment: What I specifically want to know is to say that I think that there's a  bug in the implementation of selector bar:withBaz: in class Foo, and a shorthand used in written conversations about it.

Comment: I would use Foo -bar:withBaz: but I don't think "shorthand" is part of the culture of Objective-C ;-)